# Not able to replace text during search operation

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

I am currently search a word document using the office-js api and find all instances of a token which is being placed in the word doc.  However when I am trying to replace the matching token I am getting `debug.errorlocation = "Range.insertParagraph"`.  Seems like the operation should work the way it is written, however it does not replace the desired word when search result is found.

**Sample string**

```
 Our strategy is to consider ~~client~~​'s​ business needs, and our audit will spec​​ifically focus on these related key factors:
```

**Code**

```
        Word.run(function (context) {
        var content = contentObject.Content.replace(/<img[^>"']*((("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))[^"'>]*)*>/g, "");
        var range = context.document.getSelection().insertHtml(content, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        var clientName;
        paragraphs.load(paragraphs, range, 'text');
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            for (var x = 0; x < paragraphs.items.length; x++) {
                var paragraph = paragraphs.items[x];
                var styleType = paragraphs.items[x].text.toString().match(/~~([^]*?)~~/g);
                if (paragraphs.items[x].text.search("~~") >= 0 && styleType[0] != "~~/picture~~") {
                    var styleValue = styleType[0].toString().replace(/[\]~~)}[{(]/g, '').trim();
                    paragraph.style = styleValue;
                }

                if(paragraphs.items[x].style === "/Title Page Client Name")
                {
                    var name = paragraphs.items[x].text;
                    clientName = name;
                }
            }
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                var searchResults = context.document.body.search('~~client~~', { ignoreSpace: true });
                context.load(searchResults);
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
    error location>>  searchResults.items[i].insertParagraph(clientName, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                    }
                    clientName = "";
                })
            })
        })
        .then(context.sync)
        .then(cleanTags())
        .catch(function (error) {
            feedBackMessage(error.description);
        })
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue which was causing me the error was that I was using `.insertParagraph` where the word api was expecting a paragraph insertion and not just a word.  I think it is awesome that this api is designed well enough to actually detect a paragraph vs simple text insertion.  For the record, if someone is going to make an insertion of text (just one word), they will need to use `.insertText` .

**Wording Code**

```
 return context.sync().then(function () {
                var searchResults = context.document.body.search('~~client~~', { ignoreSpace: true });
                context.load(searchResults);
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
                        searchResults.items[i].insertText(clientName, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                    }
                    clientName = "";
                    return context.sync().then(function () {

                    })
                })
            })
```